# Why is OnCollisionEnter getting called twice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got a *Cube*(player) and a *Plane*(floor) in my Scene. Both have `Colliders` attached to them and there is a `RigidBody` component attached only to the *Cube*. *Cube* is positioned above the *Plane*.

*Cube* has a script attached to it which looks for Collisions.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("...........................Collision");
    }
```

**PROBLEM:**

When the Plane and the Cube collides, the message gets printed twice.

> ...........................Collision
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
> jump:OnCollisionEnter(Collision) (at Assets/jump.cs:34)
>
> ...........................Collision
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
> jump:OnCollisionEnter(Collision) (at Assets/jump.cs:34)

Why is this happening? Is collision happening twice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, both logs seems to be coming from the *`jump.cs`* script at line **34** so we can safely say that the problem is just from one script not from many scripts.

> Why is this happening?

Here are the possible reasons:

**1**.Your script with the `OnCollisionEnter` function is attached to multiple GameObjects. Those multiple GameObject's are the two GameObject's that are colliding with one another. When they collide, `OnCollisionEnter` is called multiple times.

[image]

**2**.Your script with the `OnCollisionEnter` function is attached to the-same GameObject multiple times.

[image]

**3**.Both Colliding GameObjects are colliding, exiting then colliding again. This is possible but not likely in this case but it is worth mentioning it.

You can verify this by adding `OnCollisionExit` too:

```
void OnCollisionExit(Collision collisionInfo) 
{
        print("Collision Out: " + gameObject.name);
}
```

Then check which order the logs are printed with the `OnCollisionEnter` function.

**4**.You have more than one colliders on each GameObject that are currently colliding. If you need to use multiple colliders as a compound collider, add them to a child empty GameObject then put them in a different tag so that you can ignore them from script.

[image]

---

> Is collision happening twice?

Only you can answer this since the scene is in front of you.

Replace:

```
Debug.Log("...........................Collision");
```

with

```
Debug.Log("Collision: " + gameObject.name);
```

If the name of the GameObjects in both log are the-same then yes, it is likely happening twice.

Comment: Also there is only one Box Collider  attached to the cube.. and one to the plane

Comment: You don't need to make many comments. You can just put it in one comment. How about *#3*. If everything you said is true then zip that simple project, upload it to somewhere and put link here. I will take a look at it.

Comment: There were 2 colliders attached to the plane. `Mesh collider`(which I didn't see earlier) and a `Box Collider`.

Comment: No problem and you are welcome. I just wanted to make sure that you didn't accept answer that didn't solve your problem. Happy coding!

Comment: Hey, sorry to disturb you but I need to know this. Does the cube bounce back after it hits the surface?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have your scene. If you want something to bounceback you have to attach Physics Material to it. You can Google this. There are many articles for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088190/trying-to-understand-unity  please see this question

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be about the mesh collider. I had the same problem and when I changed the mesh collider to a box collider, the problem disappeared. My guess for the cause of this is the multiple collision lines within the mesh collider. Give it a try.

Comment: This happened to me as well.