# Trying to understand Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Cube(player) and a Plane(floor) in my Scene. Both have Colliders attached to them and there is a RigidBody component attached only to the Cube. Cube is placed on the Plane.

**LOGS**

[image]

I don't understand why am I getting those last 3 values.(These too are values for `dis` value)

**CODE**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class jump : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float initialPos = 0.5f ;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        //Debug.Log(rb.velocity.magnitude);


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {


            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0f , 1f , 0f) * 10 ;
            Debug.Log(rb.velocity);
        }



        if (rb.velocity.y > 0  && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            float dis = rb.transform.position.y - initialPos;
            Debug.Log(dis);

            rb.velocity += new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f) * Physics.gravity.y;

            //Debug.Log(rb.velocity);
            //Debug.Log("I am here");
            //rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        Debug.Log(rb.velocity);
        Debug.Log("...........................Collision " + gameObject.name);


    }
}
```

Comment: Double click on the log from the Editor and it will show you which line of code is printing what.

Comment: From here -- `float dis = rb.transform.position.y - initialPos;`. But  I don't know why. Control should go this block only if  `(rb.velocity.y > 0  && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))` is true. These messages are printed when the cube strikes the surface after the jump. During its(cube) fall velocity is negative and as soon as it hits the surface I am setting its velocity to zero.

Comment: The Y velocity is > 0 **and** the space key is not being pressed. `if (rb.velocity.y > 0  && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))`....So it is printing that value. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting) is a complete C# unity course. I don't think that the comment section will help you understand Unity and C# fully

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking. `!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))` is true but how is `rb.velocity.y > 0` getting true when I am setting `rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;` in `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`.

Comment: You're just setting the velocity to 0 for that frame. The next frame the physics engine will start moving the object again.

Comment: Why is physics engine adding that velocity? Is it because of the collision between the cube and the surface??

Comment: There  is something called gravity. Gravity is always pulling the Object down if enabled on the Rigidbody. When you set Velocity to 0 but the cube is not yet balanced, gravity will pull it down until it is sitting still. When this happens `y` may no longer be 0.