# Unity 3D: what is the correct way to detect that the collision has already been processed for another collision participant?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I have a class `CollisionHandler` which has the `OnCollisionEnter` method. Each *collideable* entity in the game has `CollisionHandler` as a component. So, when 2 objects collide the `OnCollisionEnter` method is called *twice* and it's ok because the damage and other things are processed as a result of touching object "B" by object "A" and vice versa.

In addition, each collision creates a flash effect and plays a sound of impact and of course, these effects are also played twice for each collision. Although it wouldn't be imperceptible to the player it doesn't seem to be correct anyway. In order to prevent it, I came up with the following solution: I save the current frame number in another collision participant so it will know that these effects have been played already by the first one.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    // Calculate the damage caused by `this.gameObject` to `collision.gameObject`.
    // ...

    // Play an impact sound and show a visual effect.
    if (thisObject.CollisionFrameId != Time.frameCount)
    {
        otherObject.CollisionFrameId = Time.frameCount;
        // play sound
        // show hit effect
    }
}
```

Although it works I'm not sure (I'm a novice in Unity) that it's the best practice and if so please suggest other possible solutions.

Note that I didn't ask ["Why is OnCollisionEnter getting called twice?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084505/why-is-oncollisionenter-getting-called-twice). I know why it happens. My question is about the other, though it does mention the name of the same function it still doesn't asks the same.

Comment: All solutions I made up in my mind within 5 minutes include some flag or value I would read and compare in order to know that someone else already handled this collision. rather storing the current time/framecount sounds even more logical! So I would say if this works already, good solution ;)

Comment: If your code is being called twice, check where it's being called from. You should not have to handle collision of two different objects from both objects. Put the collision code on the "smarter" of the two objects and go from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is OnCollisionEnter getting called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084505/why-is-oncollisionenter-getting-called-twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a GetComponent on the other object with one of your scripts (or the same script) and set the RecentCollisionObject to the current script or gameObject (and maybe a given time frame just for additional safety (if only one triggers it, but not the other for some reason)).

On each collision you check if RecentCollisionObject is the other object (and if no more than ~0.01 seconds has passed). If true, you know *that* particular collision must already have been processed by the other object just now, so reset all values from that other object and do nothing else. So the next collision which occurs, no matter how soon, will do this cycle anew and work as expected.

This way you let only the first to trigger the collide code execute your code (like a sound). The point is that both collision events are ran in the same frame, so no matter which triggers first, you can prevent the second from running.

Comment: I like your idea of an object, but I don't think it makes sense to lean on 0.01 seconds. Why exactly 0.01? It should work just without any timing.

Comment: It would be just a safety mechanism in the case that only one of the 2 colliding objects trigger their collision events. I am not sure if that case even exists, but if it does, having that is necessary - otherwise you get weird behavior on subsequent collisions. Instead of 0.01 seconds you can of course also take the next Update time frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unity Tag System, you tag action to occur when colliding with that specific tagged object.

As example:

```
internal void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Oject Tag") {
            this.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayOneShot (objectTagSoundClip);
        }
```

Just need a audio to play placed in game object.

Comment: In my case, every object should play audio on impact.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 2 Colliders. If so you could check if boxcollider for example is colliding only. You could also try on Collision leave. Hope it helps.