# Unity3d two collisions occurring when only one should

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

My object is colliding twice with something when it shouldn't be.
Here is my code:

```cs
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectCollision : MonoBehaviour {
    int score, nbLives, nbCoinsCollectedPerLevel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        nbCoinsCollectedPerLevel = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        string tagName = coll.collider.gameObject.tag;

        if (tagName == "pick_me") {
            Destroy(coll.collider.gameObject);
            //score++;
            score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
            score++;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);

            nbCoinsCollectedPerLevel++;

            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "level1" && nbCoinsCollectedPerLevel >= 5) {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("level2");
            }
            print("score" + score);
        }

        if (tagName == "avoid_me" || tagName == "reStarter") {
            Destroy(coll.collider.gameObject);
            nbLives = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("nbLives");
            nbLives--;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("nbLives", nbLives);
            if (nbLives >= 0)
                SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
            else SceneManager.LoadScene("lose");
            print("lives" + nbLives);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collisionInfo) {
        print("Collision Out: " + gameObject.name);

        if (tagName == "endOfLevelTwo") {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("win");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to find the root problem with this code as suggested in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084505/why-is-oncollisionenter-getting-called-twice#:%7E:text=Your%20script%20with%20the%20OnCollisionEnter,OnCollisionEnter%20is%20called%20multiple%20times.)

```cs
void OnCollisionExit(Collision collisionInfo) {
    print("Collision Out: " + gameObject.name);
}
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why are you calling `OnCollisionExit` on a 2D object instead of `OnCollisionExit2D`?

Comment: Even when calling OnCollisionExit2D I still get no output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collisionInfo) {
    Debug.Log("Collision Out: " + collisionInfo.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: I still lose two lives from one collision. Please help. Thanks

Comment: I get output now but I still lose two lives from one collision when I collide with the floor. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Add a Debug statement to print the lives before and after reducing it. This is help you understand where the problem might be.